# How to set padding of all widgets inside a window or frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I create a window with two buttons and set the padding of both of them.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
Button(window, text="Click Me").pack(padx=10, pady=10)
Button(window, text="Click Me").pack(padx=10, pady=10)
window.mainloop()
```

I want to remove `padx` and `pady` parameter from `pack()` and getting the same result.  How can I do this?

Comment: Related: [Padding specified in style ignored by Ttk Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28443818/3357935)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you want. There is no global configuration for defining the padx and pady values of `pack` in order to eliminate the need to explicitly include the values when calling `pack`. Though, you can put the values in variable so that if you want to change the value later, you only have to change it in one place.

```
padx = 10
pady = 10
Button(...).pack(padx=padx, pady=pady)
```

Of course, you can also define your own `pack` command that automatically applies whatever value you want each time it is called.

There are almost certainly better ways to solve your actual problem, but for the contrived example in the question the best you can do is use the `padx` and `pady` parameters in each call to `pack()`.

Answer (score 11):

You can do the following if the widgets are in a frame or the main `tk` window:

```
for child in frame_name.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: @BryanOakley, this seems to do what was asked, but you said is not possible. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Felipe this solution still does assign the padding to each individual item. I expect what @BrianOakley means is that there isn't something equivalent to `frame_name.grid_configure_children(padx=10, pady=10)`

Comment: @Felipe: the question specifically asked how to set a global padding value without specifying it when creating the widget. I assumed that also meant they didn't want to have to specify it when calling `pack_configure` at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

```
def pack_configure_recursive(widget, **kwargs):
    stack = list(widget.winfo_children())
    while stack:
        descendent = stack.pop()
        stack.extend(descendent.winfo_children())
        descendent.pack_configure(**kwargs)

...

pack_configure_recursive(window, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass Button and redefine the pack() method:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MyButton(ttk.Button):
    def pack(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().pack(padx=10, pady=10, *args, **kwargs)

root=tk.Tk()
MyButton(text="Hello").pack()
MyButton(text="World").pack()
root.mainloop()
```